# Perforce not downloading file even with forced Get Revision

Tags: perforce

After too much time of searching what could be the cause of a really strange but simple-looking problem and not finding anything on the internets, I came here to dip in the knowledge of the people of StackOverflow. Here is my situation:

In P4V, I right-click on a file > `Get Revision...` > `Get latest revision` selected, with `Force Operation (replace file even if you already have the revision specified)` checked.

[image: Screenshot: Getting the latest revision with the "Force operation" option]

But then, in the console panel: `file(s) up-to-date. no files updated`

[image: Screenshot: File is not updated]

What is going on? What is the `Force Operation` option for, if it doesn't force the operation?

Comment: One suggestion--try "Show In-->Explorer" (Or whatever your OS equivalent is) from P4V to make sure the file you think you are syncing is the file you are syncing (and, perhaps, temporarily rename the file to see if you get a fresh one). It might help you with troubleshooting this crazy behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red check mark indicates that the file is open for edit (or “checked out” in P4V’s parlance), which protects it from being updated by a sync operation (that’s “get” to P4V).  The “force” sync option will overwrite a file that’s manually been made writable, or a file whose contents have accidentally gotten out of sync with the depot through some other misadventure, but it will not overwrite a file that has been explicitly opened for edit, since an opened file is assumed to have local changes that have not been submitted.

Right-click the file and “Revert”.  That will explicitly discard your local changes and return the local file to its state as of the last time you synced it from the depot.